# I can't syntonize free-air channels in VLC UBUNTU

Tags: configuration, vlc, tv

After spending many hours of my life reading forums, blogs and posts here and in Stack OverFlow, I come here for some help, because I couldnt solve my problem and... not only that, but my computer crashed because of trying some other programs like VLC. I've just installed VLC to syntonize free-air channels with my TV tuner, I get the connection, but I cant see any channel, and I don't know how to change it (free-air TV has just 3 channels: 8, 10, 12). I've tested every option in VLC but I had no luck. It displays interruption gray screen as in TV. I'm from Argentina, I don't know if it has something to do with. I'm so noob at this things as you can see. I've read many comments that it's impossible to change or search channels in VLC, but I'm not sure it's that way. Any help or idea would be appreciated!

Comment: What make and model is your TV capture card? Is it DVB-T or analog?

Comment: @Cornelius , My TV capture card is Encore ENLTV-FM3. It's a TV-PCI syntonizer. In product description it says: "3-in-1: Analog TV Tuner / Digital Video Recorder / FM Radio".

Answer (score 0):

That capture card is analog. It can only be used for analog TV.

It is based on SAA7134 ? Run in a terminal `sudo lspci | grep Multimedia`. If so you'll have to configure the driver. I'm not actually sure if the following commands (some of them are based on [Ezequiel A. Ribeiro](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5z1FFboZlOb4heolzuEbGw) video [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iT7NWv4mUGg) on Youtube) will still work on the latest Ubuntu but you can try.

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-oss tvtime
```

Edit this:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modules
```

Add at the end and save:

```
saa7134
```

Now, edit this file:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/saa7134
```

Add in that file and the save:

```
options saa7134 card=3 tuner=37 ir_debug=1
```

This should be all to get the video working (after a restart *). Only if the audio doesn't work proceed to the next part.

**For audio:**

Run `tvtime` first. Ignore any errors.

Edit this:

```
gedit ~/.tvtime/tvtime.xml
```

And add:

```
 <option name="MixerDevice" value="hw:0/Line"/>
```

before the last line

```
</tvtime>
```

Now run `tvtime` from terminal (no `sudo`). The only otuput should be:

```
Running tvtime 1.0.2.
Reading configuration from /etc/tvtime/tvtime.xml
Reading configuration from /home/..../.tvtime/tvtime.xml
```

If there are errors, post them in the question to see what can be done.

VLC doesn't work for me either. When trying to open the capture card (similar to yours) and set the frequency I get:

```
[0x7fb340000e68] v4l2 demux error: unknown video standard "PAL_BG:v4l2-tuner-frequency=191250"
```

But TVTime works great.

---

* To skip restart just run in the terminal

```
sudo rmmod saa7134
sudo modprobe saa7134
```

Comment: Great info, so, have you already tested these commands? do they work? So I should install TVTime instead of VLC, shouldnt I?

Comment: @Lucarolina I have a similar card - the difference is that it is based on BT878 so instead of `saa7134` I have `bttv` module. Similar commands work on my PC. Anyway these commands won't do any harm to your OS and PC so it's worth trying.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try it out! I hope it works, this is a real headache for me, I swear! haha because I'm just a programmer, and I'm not so cool at configuring things referring to TV and Audio! although I use Ubuntu 4 years ago.